# How do I deselect a text entry box/update it to read only when enter is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, text, widget

I have been working on some simple UI recently and this ha me baffled. I have checked several different stackoverflow threads on the entry boxes as well as other documentation and a video tutorial but have found nothing on this.

I have a text box as part of the UI. The user is supposed to select it, input a name, and press enter, at which point I'll use the .get() function to get the name. However, I'd also like to remove the cursor/swap it to read only mode.

This is where the problem arises. If I root.bind the enter key to .configure(state="readonly") or state="disabled" it doesn't wait until the enter key is pressed to disable or make the entry box read only

Does anybody know how I could make this work or why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set the `NAME_OF_ENTRY_WIDGET.bind('<Return>', FUNCTION_NAME_HERE)` to a function, then in the function set the state of the entry widget to disabled

```py
def FUNCTION_NAME_HERE():
    TEXT = NAME_OF_ENTRY_WIDGET.get()

    ....

    NAME_OF_ENTRY_WIDGET['state'] = DISABLED
    return TEXT
```

You may have to pass the widget as an argument to the function

Comment: You sir, are a legend. I plugged this into my code, and with one minor edit (swapped just the function name to "lambda e: function_name()") and it works like a dream. Thanks